# OutputStream java

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Как записать число `double` в байтовый поток?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно обернуть `OutputStream` в [`DataOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html), а затем использовать метод [`DataOutputStream::writeDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeDouble-double-):

```
OutputStream output = ...
double число_для_записи = ...

DataOutputStream dataOutput = new DataOutputStream(output);
dataOutput.writeDouble(число_для_записи);
```